# MongoDB Grouping

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm attempting to figure out the average age grouped by gender. Expected output should be

```
{'_id': {'gender': 'M'},{'avg': '27.1}}
{'_id': {'gender': 'F'}},{'avg': '29.0}}
```

This is my code below

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$project" : { 
            "_id" : {'gender':"$gender"},
            "avg": {"$avg":"$age"},
        }
    },
    {"$group" : {"_id":"$_id"}},

]

for doc in db.user.aggregate(pipeline):
    print(doc)
```

Right now the out put is:

```
{'_id': {'gender': 'M'}}
{'_id': {'gender': 'F'}}
```

Any help would be appreciated! I know this may be a easy one.....

Comment: Sample documents please..

Answer (score 0):

the following pipeline will give you the average age of each gender. you need to group before projecting.

```java
    [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$gender",
                "avrg": {
                    "$avg": "$age"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "gender": "$_id",
                "avg": "$avrg",
                "_id": 0
            }
        }
    ]
```

here's the c# test program that generated the above:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Person : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            (new[] {
                new Person{ Name = "one", Gender = "M", Age = 30},
                new Person{ Name = "two", Gender = "M", Age = 30},
                new Person{ Name = "three", Gender = "F", Age = 40},
                new Person{ Name = "four", Gender = "F", Age = 40},
            }).Save();

            var res = DB.Queryable<Person>()
                        .GroupBy(p => p.Gender)
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            gender = g.Key,
                            avg = g.Average(p => p.Age)
                        })
                        .ToArray();

            foreach (var r in res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Gender: {r.gender} Average: {r.avg}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```